# Estou tentando criar vários álbuns no meu site mas continua aparecendo apenas o primeiro criado

Tags: html5

Segue a baixo o meu código:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.lbox {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
ul {
    width: 800px auto ;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    margin: 100px auto;
}
.min {
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.lbox:target {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(10,10,10,0.7);
}
.box-img {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 150px auto;
}
.btn {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
#prev {
    left: 5%;
    top: 45%;
}
#next {
    right: 5%;
    top: 45%;
}
#close {
    top: 0;
    right: 2px;
}
.box-img img {
    opacity: 0;
}

.lbox:target .box-img img {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 250ms linear;    

}
```

```html
<h2>Quarto 1<h2>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#img1"><img src="3cama.html" alt="" class="min"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#img2"><img src="quartdo.html" alt="" class="min"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#img3"><img src="quartoun.html" alt="" class="min"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#img4"><img src="quartsou.html" alt="" class="min"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#img5"><img src="quartuno.html" alt="" class="min"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#img6"><img src="quarto.html" alt="" class="min"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#img7"><img src="quartum.html" alt="" class="media"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#img8"><img src="varan.html" alt="" class="min"></a></li>
</ul>
   <div class="lbox" id="img1">
    <div class="box-img">
        <a href="#img8" class="btn" id="prev">&#171;</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn" id="close">X</a>
        <img src="3cama.html" alt="">
        <a href="#img2" class="btn" id="next">&#187;</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="lbox" id="img2">
    <div class="box-img">
        <a href="#img1" class="btn" id="prev">&#171;</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn" id="close">X</a>
        <img src="quartdo.html" alt="">
        <a href="#img3" class="btn" id="next">&#187;</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="lbox" id="img3">
    <div class="box-img">
        <a href="#img2" class="btn" id="prev">&#171;</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn" id="close">X</a>
        <img src="quartoun.html" alt="">
        <a href="#img4" class="btn" id="next">&#187;</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="lbox" id="img4">
    <div class="box-img">
        <a href="#img3" class="btn" id="prev">&#171;</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn" id="close">X</a>
        <img src="quartsou.html" alt="">
           <a href="#img5" class="btn" id="next">&#187;</a>
    </div>
  <div class="lbox" id="img5">
    <div class="box-img">
        <a href="#img4" class="btn" id="prev">&#171;</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn" id="close">X</a>
        <img src="quartuno.html" alt="">
           <a href="#img6" class="btn" id="next">&#187;</a>
    </div>
    </div>
  <div class="lbox" id="img6">
    <div class="box-img">
        <a href="#img5" class="btn" id="prev">&#171;</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn" id="close">X</a>
        <img src="quarto.html" alt="">
           <a href="#img7" class="btn" id="next">&#187;</a>
    </div>
  <div class="lbox" id="img8">
    <div class="box-img">
        <a href="#img7" class="btn" id="prev">&#171;</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn" id="close">X</a>
        <img src="varan.html" alt="">
           <a href="#img1" class="btn" id="next">&#187;</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Depois eu apenas repeti tudo trocando as fotos e suas numerações.

Comment: Vc está usando algum script ou jquery, ou é só css e html que vc usa pra fazer isso?

Comment: já experimentou comentar     `.lbox {
    //visibility: hidden;
    //opacity: 0;
}` ;

Comment: Ola hugocsl, estou usando apenas html e css.

Answer (score 0):

O elemento `<img>` não aceita como atributo para a propriedade `src` um arquivo `html`, sua proposta é exibir imagens.

`<img src="quartoun.html" alt="" class="min">` (Isso nunca vai funcionar...)